# How to handle temporary redirect 307 amazon S3 when using CORS

Tags: javascript, ajax, amazon-s3, cors, fine-uploader

I am using a file uploader (fine-uploader) to upload some files directly to S3. The uploading process works fine until amazon responds with temporary redirect (307). Then, the upload fails with the following error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://testuploads.s3.amazonaws.com/.
>   Redirect from 'http://testuploads.s3.amazonaws.com/' to
>   'http://testuploads.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/' has been blocked by
>   CORS policy: Request requires preflight, which is disallowed to follow
>   cross-origin redirect.

Comment: There's nothing that can be done about this, as far as I can tell. According to the CORS spec, [non-2xx responses to preflighted requests are treated as errors](https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#cross-origin-request-with-preflight-0).

Comment: How long has it been since this bucket was created?  This typically only happens for a short time after bucket creation.